# Description for VS Code Extension not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, marketplace

I'm having trouble with my extension on the Visual Studio Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Astro.Astro

A description won't add, but on my GitHub repo, it will. Does anyone know how to fix it?

My GitHub:https://github.com/bereketsemagn/

Github Repo: https://github.com/bereketsemagn/astro-theme

Answer (score 0):

The README.md file inside the extension is wrong

```
# omnist
```

You have to change the way you package the extension.

How is it possible that the version of the extension on the market place is 0.0.55 and in your commits the last version is 0.0.11.

Why do you commit your node-modules directory?

Having all commit messages as

```
updates
```

is not very informative.

Why have you removed `.gitignore` in `c8d1787`

All in all your git repo is a big mess and you should start from scratch

Comment: I am unable to change omnist still, and I deleted the README file, what should I do next?